# Coding pattern for periodically evaluating test data set during training in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I current have separate scripts for training and evaluation. I would like to evaluate on test set after say 1000 training steps, then log the evaluation accuracy as part of the summary. Since the input reader is part of the graph, I'm not quite sure how I can alternating using a training data reader and testing data reader.

Comment: Common pattern is to use separate scripts for training and evaluation, running in parallel. You can configure your Saver to checkpoint once every 1000 training steps

Comment: Yaroslav, by "parallel", do you mean running two scripts simultaneously or interleave two scripts? In the first case, would there be potential race condition, if evaluation scripts attempt to use a checkpoint while training script is in the middle of writing it?

Comment: Simultaneously. The code for reading latest checkpoint has logic to prevent race condition -- it retrieves name of latest checkpoint from another file which indicates that checkpoint is ready

Comment: My another concern with simultaneous training and evaluation is GPU memory requirement. I'm using a machine with only 1 GPU.

Comment: Another alternative is that you can use separate Graph and separate Session objects for evaluation in the same process

Comment: I assume you are implying sharing variables between the two graphs, hence reducing memory usage?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov do you have an example of using separate Graph and Session objects for evaluation and training in the same process?