# How to smoothly produce Tensorflow auc summaries for training and test sets?

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow [describes](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) writing file summaries to visualize graph execution.

I envision three stages:

1. training the data (with optimization)
2. measuring accuracy on the training set (no optimization)
3. measuring accuracy on the test set (no optimization!)

I'd like all stages in the same script, as in the evaluate function of the [wide_and_deep tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep), but with the low-level API.  I'd like three different graphs for stats like loss or AUC, one for each stage.

Suppose I use one session, and in each stage I define an AUC summary op:

```
# define auc
auc, auc_op = tf.metrics.auc(labels, predictions)
# summary scalar to track it
tf.summary.scalar("auc", auc_op, family=family_name)
# merge all summaries for evaluation and later writing
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
...
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step_num)
```

There are three graphs, but the first graph has all three runs on it, and the second graph has the last two runs (see below).  What's worse, each stage starts from the previous state.  This makes sense, because all the variables from the previous stages are still around.

I could use a different session for each stage, but that would throw away the model as well.

What is the smooth way to handle this?

I'd like to just clear some of the summary variables.  I've tried re-initializing some variables, looked at [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049664/coding-pattern-for-periodically-evaluating-test-data-set-during-training-in-tens) questions, read about name scope and variable scope and tried not to re-use variables for AUC, read about [variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) and [sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow#37534656), looked into [pruning nodes](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/remove_training_nodes) (though I don't understand it), etc.  I have not made it work yet.

I am using the low-level API.  I saw something like this in the high-level API in [_eval_metric_ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py#L591), but I don't understand how they 'clear' the different stages.  With name_scope?

Do I have to save and load the model into a new session just for this, or is there some clean way to graph each summary separately?

[image: three graphs]

Answer (score 0):

The metric ops will be local variables, so you could run `tf.local_variables_initializer()` in your Session, which will reset all of your metrics. You could also look through the local variables collection for those with "auc" in the name if you wanted to be a bit more discerning. The high-level way to do this would be to use an [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators), which will manage metrics for you.

Comment: Thanks! I have to use the low-level API. I ended up creating a new summary writer and *not* using merge_all, which would continue writing to the old metrics. Rather, I made sure to only write the metrics for the latest stage.